# Why does Eigen matrix calculations return zero when std::thread is used for multi threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I am trying to implement multi threading to distribute certain cpu intensive operations to different threads. However any Eigen declarations always returns zero when multi threading is used.  Following is an example code that demonstrates this issue

```
#include "../Eigen/Core"
#include "../Eigen/LU"
#include "../Eigen/Sparse"
#include "../Eigen/StdVector"
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


void Multiply_3x3 (MatrixXd& matrix1, MatrixXd& matrix2, MatrixXd& results);

int main()
{

  MatrixXd a(3, 3);
  MatrixXd b(3, 3);
  MatrixXd c(3,3);

  a<<2,4,3,1,5,7,0,2,3;
  b<<2,4,3,1,5,7,0,2,3;
  
  //Multiply_3x3(a,b,c);
  std::thread thread_multi(Multiply_3x3, a, b, c);
  thread_multi.join();

  cout << " *** In Main Program ***" << endl;
  cout <<c(0,0)<<" , "<< c(0,1)<<" , "<< c(0,1)<<endl;
  cout<<c(1,0)<<" , "<<c(1,1)<<" , "<<c(1,1)<<endl;
  cout<<c(2,0)<<" , "<<c(2,1)<<" , "<<c(2,1)<<endl;


}

void Multiply_3x3 (MatrixXd& matrix1, MatrixXd& matrix2, MatrixXd& results)
{
  results = matrix1 * matrix2;

  cout << " *** In Multiply_3x3 ***" << endl;
  cout<<results(0,0)<<" , "<<results(0,1)<<" , "<<results(0,1)<<endl;
  cout<<results(1,0)<<" , "<<results(1,1)<<" , "<<results(1,1)<<endl;
  cout<<results(2,0)<<" , "<<results(2,1)<<" , "<<results(2,1)<<endl<<endl<<endl;  
}
```

The output from this run is

```
 *** In Multiply_3x3 ***
8 , 34 , 34
7 , 43 , 43
2 , 16 , 16


 *** In Main Program ***
1.69122e-306 , 1.95819e-306 , 1.95819e-306
9.34612e-307 , 6.23037e-307 , 6.23037e-307
9.34602e-307 , 6.2304e-307 , 6.2304e-307
```

As shown in the output the results are correct in the function Multiply_3x3. However the returned values are zero. If I don't use std:thread and call the function as shown in the commended section **(//Multiply_3x3(a,b,c);)** the results are correct in the calling function. Wondering if anyone could point out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply `std::ref` to all matrices `a`, `b` and `c` when constructing `thread`. Without this, `std::thread` makes a copy passed arguments and operates on them, changing the copy of `c` matrix instead original `c` matrix defined in `main`.

```
  std::thread thread_multi(Multiply_3x3, std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c));
  thread_multi.join();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rErKMbWGs)

---

Note, without `std::ref` your code doesn't compile on G++, it seems you are using Microsoft Visual which has some extensions (enabled by default) - for example, binding temporary object to *lvalue* reference. That is why your code was compiled. You can turn off this feature by adding `/Za` to compiler's flags.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how you got this to compile and work. I'm not able to compile this on MSVC.

But, remember that the `std::thread`'s constructor doesn't care about the type of the arguments passed in. It simply copies the arguments to an internal storage (accessible by the newly created thread) and are passed in as temporaries (rvalues) to the callable object.

For example,

```
void foo(std::string& s);
std::thread t1(foo, "hello");
std::string arg("hello");
std::thread t2(foo, arg);
```

will not work because it's not possible to construct a non-const reference from a temporary.

But

```
void foo(const std::string& s);
std::thread t1(foo, "hello");
std::string arg("hello");
std::thread t2(foo, arg);
```

is okay because the function takes in a `const` reference.

So you just have to wrap the arguments that a need a reference with `std::ref`, so that the function is not given a temporary copy. It will then compile and work properly.

Comment: I am not sure why it was compiling. May have to do with not using /Za option as rafix07 indicated.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure either! But it's not enable by default for me, as rafix07 mentioned. I don't see the /Za flag on the command line for my project's build config. I'm on Visual Studio 2019 16.7 and my Compiler Version is 19.27.29112.